Facing problem with BLASTx using BioPython in Google Colab
I'm trying to BLASTX a sequence using Biopython in Google Colab. Here is the code I am using. I'm not able to understand why I am getting an empty list [] for alignments.
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastx", "nr", test_seq.seq, expect=1e-05)
blast_record = NCBIXML.read(result_handle)
alignments = []
for alignment in tqdm(blast_record.alignments):
  for hsp in alignment.hsps:
      alignments.append({
          "title": alignment.title,
          "length": alignment.length,
          "e_value": hsp.expect,
          "score": hsp.score,
          "query": hsp.query,
          "match": hsp.match,
          "subject": hsp.sbjct
      })
len(alignments) # its coming 0 because its empty

As a note, here is the test sequence I am using, which is giving proper results in BLASTX on NCBI server in NCBI NR database. Any help would be very helpful.
>test_seq
GCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCGCGGCGCGCGACTGCCTGGCCATGAATGCTTTCTCCAAGCTGCTGCGCGT
GCTGACCACGCCCTCCATGCTGCACAACCTGTGCAACAGCGACCAAGGCGTGCACGTGCTGATCCGGCTC
ATCAAGCTGAGCTCGCCGCCAGAGACGGCTTTCATTGCTGACCAGGTCCTGCACGACTTGGCTGACATGG
TGGTCAGCAAGGGCGGCGCTCTGGTGGTCTGCACCCTGGTCGACCGCCTGGCCGTCGCGGCCAGCTGCGA
CAACCCGGGGGTGGTGGAGCGGGCCACGGGCGCGGTTGTGCGCATGTGCAGCCACCTGTGCCAGCACCAT
CGCGCGCTGCAGCAGTGTGCGCGGCACCAGTACCTGGGTCCCAAGGTCGTTGAGCTGCTGCAGTGCGGCC
TGCCCGCTGTGGATGCCTTCAAGATGGGGTTTGAGCTGGTCCAGAACGCGCCCGCGCTGGCGGCCACCCG
CCACGGCAGCCGCACGCTGCAGCTGCTCACGGAGATTCGGGCCGCCGATGCGCGGTCGCGAGAGATGCTG
CGAGACGTGGTCTGCCACGCGTCCAAGGCGCTGCAGGGCCACTTTGGCCAGCTGGCGGCCAAGGGGGAGA
CGGGAGGGCCCGCCCTGGTCCGCGCCCTGCTGGACTACCTGCTGGCGGAGCGGGAGGACGACTGGGTGGT
GCAGATCACCTGGGAGCTGCTGGCGGCGGGCAGTGAGCTGCGGCGGGACCGGGAGGCACATGACTTGCTG
GTGCACAGCCTGGCCCTGCCGCTGTGGCGCCCCACCGAGGCGCAGCAGCACTGGGCGGCGCTTGCGGCCG
CTGGCGTGGATGTGGCAGCCCTCAAGCCCAAGGTGGATGCAGCCAAGCAGCACCAGCCGCGGCTTCCGGA
GCGGGTGCTGGCATCGCTGTCCGAGGTGCAGCCTTCGTCACCTGCAGAGGTCAGCGCCAAGCAGCGCACG
AGCTGTCTTCCCCGCTCCGCATGCTCAGGGCCGGGCTGCTCCTGCCTGCCCGGAGTGGTGAGCGGGATCC
TGACGTGCCTCCCTGCCCCTCGCTTGTCCAATGATGTTCTATATTCCATCGTCGCAGGCTGTGCGGCGCT
TCCCTTACTATCTGCGGGATGGAAGCCAGGCGGCTCGCAACTCTGTGCTCAGAAAGCAGCAGGGCGCAGG
GCAGCCAGCCGTGCCCCCGCCGCCCCCGCCGCGGGAGCAGCAGCAGCCCAAGGCGCCCCCTGGCTTTGGG
GCGGCAGGAGCCGCTGCAGCGCCAGCGGCTCCTGCGGCTGCCAAGGTGCCCCCACCCGGCTTTGCGGCAG
CGCCGTCGGCGGCGCCAGCAGCAGCGCCAGCGGCCATCACTTTCCCAAATGGCGCAAGCGTGCCCATGCC
GCAGCCCTATGGCGCCAGCAGCAGCAGCGCTGCGCCTGCAGCCAGCAAGGCGGTTCCGCCGCCAGCCCCA
CAGCAGCCAGCTGTCGTAGCCGCTGCTGCGATGGTGCCCCCGCCCTCGCCCCTCAAGCCTGCAGCCCCTC
CGCAGCAGCCAGTGGCACTGCCACCGCCTGCCCCCATGCAGCCAGCAGCAGCGCCCCTGGTGCCTGCACC
TGTGCCGCAGCCCGCGCCTGTGCAGCCACCAGTGGCAGCGCCCCGGCCCCCGGCACCTGTGCCGCAGCCT
GCTGTGCAGCCACCTGTGGCGGTGCGGCCACCAGTGCCACCACCTGCGCCTGTGGCACCCGGCATGAATG
CAGCAGCCCGGCCATTTGTGCAGGCAGTGCCTGCCCCTGCGGCGCAACCCCTGCCCCCGCACCTGCAGCC
CAACCTGCAGCAGCAGCAACAGCCGCAGCAGCCCGCGCACCTTCAAGCGCTGCCGCCGCACCTGCGGCAG
CCGGTGGCAGCGGCAGCAGGCAGCAGTGCCGGGCAGGCGGGCACGGCAGCACCCATCACGCCTGTGCCGG
CACAGCACCCTGCGGGCGGCTTCACCGCGCCGCCTGCACCGCAGCAGCTGCTGCAGCAGCTGCTTGGCAG
CGCTGCCCCGCGGCCCGCGGTCCCGGCAGCGGCGCCAGCAGCGGTGCGGCCGCTTGCTCCGCCGCAGGCA
GCAGCAGCTCAGGGCAGCGCAGCTGCCTTTGATGGCTACGGCAGCCTCACAGAAATGCTGTCTGAGCTAA
CTGCCGCTGCGGCGCCACAGCCGGTGGCACCTGCACGCCCAGCCTACCGCCCGGCCTACCGCCCGCCTGG
AGCAGCTGCTTACCGCCCGCCCACCGCCGCGGCGCCGCCGCCACCGCCCGCGCCAGCGGCCGCACCTGCG
CCTGTTTCTGTGCCTGTGGGCATTCCAGCCCCCTCGCCTGCAACCCGGTTCCCCATGCCCGGCGCGCCAC
GGCCCGCACCGGTGCCAGCAGCTGCGGCGCCGCCGCCGCCGGCAGCGCCCGCCCGCCCGGCGGTGCCAGC
GGTGCCGGTGGCATCGGCGACCAACTGGACCTGCAGGGTGTGCACCTACCGGCATGAGGGAGCGGAGGCT
CAGTTCCTGTCCTGTGCCATGTGCGGCTCCCCACAGTCCTAGGCAGCCTGCTGTGGCAGTCCCTAGGCTG
GCTGCTGTGGCAGTCCTGGGCAGGCCGCTTGGTGGCTAGCTGGCTTCGCTGGCTCGGCAGCACTTCAACG
CTCCCACAACCTTCCATTGTTCCTTGCACTGCAACCCTTGCCCCCTGATCGCATCGCTCGCCCTTGCCTC
TTGTCATTCATGCTGCACCAACCCAGCCCCTGTGCATGTAACACCAGAGATGACCCCCCTGTTGTATTGG
GCTCGCTTGCTTTGAGGCACGGGGGTTGTTTCACAGGAGGAATGAACAGGGGGGCACATGGGACGGCTGG
GAAGAAGCAGCACAAAGAGCAACAGGAACAGAATCATCAAATGAGCATGTGGTGGTACACTTGACTTCGG
GGGATGAAGAAGAAGAGGCAGCCAGGGGTGCTGGGGCGGAGGGGGGTGTCGATCCGAGGCATCATGCCGC
CAGCGGTAAGGGTGCAAGCAGTGGGGGTGCGTATTTAGACAGCAGGGCATTCGTGGGGCAAGGAAGAGAT
GGAGGAGTGTGGCGGGGCTGGCAGGGGGTTCAATGCAGCCTTCCTGCCGCACACTTTGCAGACATGCATT
TTCCAGGGAAGAGACGAGAGGAAGAGCAGTGCGACGGGGCGGGACAGCGAAGGGGCGGGCGCACGGGGGC
GCAGTCCCGCCCATGGCGCAGCCGCCACGGCCGGAACAAACATTTTGTTTTTGATGGTACACAAACAAAC
AAACAGGAGCGATGTTAAGAGTTAGGGAGCGGAGCAATGCAGAGGTGGGTGGGCAGGTAGCAAGGCAGGG
AGCGGGTATATGCCGGGGGCGGGCCACAGTGCAGTGGCGGCATGGCGGCAGCGCCACGCTGCCGCCGCCC
ACACCGACGGCTGGGCGCCGCCACTTCAGTCGGCGAGCGTCGCGCGCGCCAGCTGCGCTTGCACAGCCGC
CGTGCCGCCGCCCTGCTCGCCAGATGCAGTGCGCACCGGCTGGGCAGCGGAAGCAGACTCCTCAGACTGC
TCCAGAGAGCTGGCAGAGTCCACCTTGCCCTTGCTGCGGCTGCCGTTGCGGCTCAGCATGTGCAGCGGCC
TGCGGCGAAGCAAGGGCGGTGCGGCGGGGGCCGCAGCCAGGGTCGGCATCCAAGCCGCAGCCGGCAGCAG
CGTGCGGTACAGAGGGCGGCTGGCCTCGGCCTGCCGGCGCTGCCAAGCATGGGTGCTATGAGGAAGCAGG
CCTGCAGAGTTGCAGGCCGGCAGGCAGGGCAGCGCCAATCAGGGCGGGCACCAGCAGTGCCAGGCTCGCC
AGCAACAAGCTGCAGCCCTTTGCCACACTCACCGCGTGTACGGCGGCTGCGACTGCTGCGACTGCTGCTG
CGCAAACGGCGTGCCGCTGTAGTGGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCGCCAGCGGGGTGCTGCGGCGGGAATGCCGGC
GATGCCATGCCGGTGCTTGTGGGGTAGCCGTAGGCAGCTGCGCCGGGCACATAGCCGCCCATCTGGCCTC
CCATCATCATGTACGGGCTGGGGGCCATGCCCCCCATGCCAGCCATTGGGCTCATGCCACCGTACTGCTG
GGCCATGCCGGCATACTGCATGCCAAAGCCGGGGCCGCCCGGCACCATGCCTGCATGCGGGTAGCCGAAC
ATGCCAAAGCCGGCGGCCGCGTAGGGGCTGGGCGGGCTGCCAAACAGCGCGCCGGGTGAGCCCACCACGG
CGCCGGGCGGGCCGCCAAAGGGCGGCAGGCCCATGCCGCCGCGGCCGCCGGCGCCGCTGGTGCTG

EDIT: By the way, to test the code, I tried running Biopython in Jupyter locally. When I tried with BLASTp with same code for a different sequence, I got this error:
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

I'm thinking there is some problem with the scraper implemented in Biopython. When attempting BLASTX, the code keeps on running for an unreasonable amount of time (>10 min. I had to stop the Kernel). Let me know if it makes sense.
Thanks

Can you show us the complete program, including any include directives so we can reproduce this locally? (not sure why you chose to undo my edit, by the way, that is really hard to read)

Is that really your sequence? You have everything, including the header on a single line? And should we assume test_seq.seq is a file? What kind of file? Simple text file? Windows line endings? Unix?

test_seq.seq is definitely a Bio.Seq.Seq object. I checked that 5 times before posting this query. NCBI servers seem to be having a problem in general, really.

Regarding the code... it's just Biopython all the way. From FASTA parsing to getting the first sequence.

That's not particularly helpful. If you're not providing at least stub code for others to see the same problem, they're less likely to help you out with a solution.

I've been able to replicate the issue you've had (or at least produce a similar issue) with the following code:
#!/usr/bin/env python

## initial setup code from 'www_blast' biopython example
## (Brad Chapman / Biopython)

# standard library
from io import StringIO

# biopython
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

from tqdm import tqdm # progress bar

# first get the sequence we want to parse from a FASTA file
test_seq = next(SeqIO.parse("test_seq.fasta", "fasta"))

# this fetch query takes a *long* time
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nr",
                               test_seq.format("fasta"),
                               expect=1e-05)

# save the results for later, in case we want to look at it
with open("m_cold_blast.out", "w") as save_file:
    blast_results = result_handle.read()
    save_file.write(blast_results)

blast_record = NCBIXML.read(result_handle)

alignments = []
for alignment in tqdm(blast_record.alignments):
  for hsp in alignment.hsps:
      alignments.append({
          "title": alignment.title,
          "length": alignment.length,
          "e_value": hsp.expect,
          "score": hsp.score,
          "query": hsp.query,
          "match": hsp.match,
          "subject": hsp.sbjct
      })
len(alignments) # result: 0

Looking at the message in the saved XML output - I'd recommend doing similar with saving and looking at intermediate data when debugging issues - I see the following:
<Iteration_message>[blastsrv4.REAL]: Error: CPU usage limit was exceeded, resulting in SIGXCPU (24).</Iteration_message>

So my guess is that your query string is too long.
After further investigation, I've come up with the following code, which is able to properly process a shorter string (280bp):
#!/usr/bin/env python

## initial setup code from 'www_blast' biopython example
## (Brad Chapman / Biopython)

# standard library
from io import StringIO

# biopython
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML

from tqdm import tqdm # progress bar

# first get the sequence we want to parse from a FASTA file
test_seq = next(SeqIO.parse("test_seq_short.fasta", "fasta"))

# this takes a long time
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastx", "nr",
                               test_seq.format("fasta"),
                               expect=1e-05)

# save the results for later, in case we want to look at it
with open("m_cold_blast.out", "w") as save_file:
    blast_results = result_handle.read()
    save_file.write(blast_results)

string_result_handle = StringIO(blast_results)
blast_record = NCBIXML.read(string_result_handle)

alignments = []
for alignment in tqdm(blast_record.alignments):
  for hsp in alignment.hsps:
      alignments.append({
          "title": alignment.title,
          "length": alignment.length,
          "e_value": hsp.expect,
          "score": hsp.score,
          "query": hsp.query,
          "match": hsp.match,
          "subject": hsp.sbjct
      })

>>> len(alignments)
4
>>> alignments
[{'title': 'gb|PRW60132.1| 60S ribosomal L15 [Chlorella sorokiniana]', 'length': 1087, 'e_value': 2.9921e-51, 'score': 466.0, 'query': 'SSSSSSAARDCLAMNAFSKLLRVLTTPSMLHNLCNSDQGVHVLIRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVLHDLADMVVSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAASC', 'match': 'SSSSSSAARDCLAMNAFSKLLRVLTTPSMLHNLCNSDQGVHVLIRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVLHDLADMVVSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAASC', 'subject': 'SSSSSSAARDCLAMNAFSKLLRVLTTPSMLHNLCNSDQGVHVLIRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVLHDLADMVVSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAASC'}, {'title': 'gb|KAI7846133.1| hypothetical protein COHA_000394 [Chlorella ohadii]', 'length': 864, 'e_value': 1.83868e-41, 'score': 394.0, 'query': 'AARDCLAMNAFSKLLRVLTTPSMLHNLCNSDQGVHVLIRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVLHDLADMVVSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAASC', 'match': 'A  DCLAM +FSKLLRVLT+ SMLHNLC SDQGVHVL+RLIKLSSPPETAFIADQV+HDLADMV SKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAASC', 'subject': 'AGHDCLAMTSFSKLLRVLTSASMLHNLCMSDQGVHVLVRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVMHDLADMVTSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAASC'}, {'title': 'ref|XP_005845358.1| hypothetical protein CHLNCDRAFT_137175 [Chlorella variabilis] >gb|EFN53256.1| hypothetical protein CHLNCDRAFT_137175 [Chlorella variabilis]', 'length': 1059, 'e_value': 2.1613e-11, 'score': 171.0, 'query': 'CLAMNAFSKLLRVLTTPSMLHNLCNSDQGVHVLIRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVLHDLADMVVSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAAS', 'match': 'C A+ A+S+LL+ LT P+M H L  SD+GV+VL++L+KL SP ET +IA+Q    + +   SK G+L V  LVDRLA  A+', 'subject': 'CTALRAYSELLKALT-PAM-HQLATSDRGVYVLVKLVKLGSPMETVYIAEQATPMVVEWSGSKDGSLFVTQLVDRLAQVAT'}, {'title': 'gb|KAI3436075.1| hypothetical protein D9Q98_002133 [Chlorella vulgaris]', 'length': 1091, 'e_value': 4.23077e-06, 'score': 132.0, 'query': 'CLAMNAFSKLLRVLTTPSMLHNLCNSDQGVHVLIRLIKLSSPPETAFIADQVLHDLADMVVSKGGALVVCTLVDRLAVAAS', 'match': 'C AM A+S+LL+ L     +HNL   D+GVH L++L+   S  E  ++A+Q    + D + SK G L    L+ RLA +A+', 'subject': 'CTAMMAYSELLKALAL--AMHNLSMRDKGVHALVKLVDTGSTLEAVYLAEQATPLMLDWMGSKDGILFAVKLIHRLAQSAA'}]


Comparing with the code you have provided, the only difference I can see is that my working result text is wrapped inside a StringIO Structure.

I tried BLASTp using a 46aa sequence. That didn't work either. When I tried a 25-sequence FASTA file in NCBI, there was the same error (CPU usage exceeded) I guess, NCBI servers are getting overwhelmed...

Yeah, I can't imagine that the query is too long. That isn't a particularly large sequence, so if it couldn't handle that, the whole blast tool would be useless.
